# Unable to find a specification for 'SquareInAppPaymentsSDK' in Objective-C Pod file

Tags: ios, objective-c, square-connect, square

I want to add `SquareInAppPaymentsSDK` in project and project is written in Objective-C. When I try to add `pod 'SquareInAppPaymentsSDK'` in my pod file and try to run `pod install` at that time I am getting this specification error.

Square has mentioned to add this line but I am not using Swift for development then what can I do it in Objective-C.

```
use_frameworks!

pod "SquareInAppPaymentsSDK"
```

Please let me know if anyone have any idea about this. Do I have to use manual installation?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this command -

```
$ pod repo update
```

in your terminal. It will sync the latest podspec files for you. Then try -

```
$ pod install
```